# Simple UDF apply function from the doc is failing with Spark 3.3

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-notebook, user-defined-functions, amazon-emr, aws-emr-studio

This simple code from the [latest doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/sql/arrow_pandas.html#grouped-map) does not work on the EMR Studio Spark cluster (current version: `3.3.1-amzn-0`)

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, 1.0), (1, 2.0), (2, 3.0), (2, 5.0), (2, 10.0)],
    ("id", "v"))

def subtract_mean(pdf: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    # pdf is a pandas.DataFrame
    v = pdf.v
    return pdf.assign(v=v - v.mean())

df.groupby("id").applyInPandas(subtract_mean, schema="id long, v double").show()
```

The error looks like this:

```
An error was encountered:
An error occurred while calling o184.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 7.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 7.0 (TID 59) (ip-10-130-55-119.us-east-1.aws.(website).com executor 7): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to run command: /usr/bin/virtualenv -p python3 --no-pip --system-site-packages virtualenv_application_1693557403809_0024_0
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.VirtualEnvFactory.execCommand(VirtualEnvFactory.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.VirtualEnvFactory.setupVirtualEnv(VirtualEnvFactory.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.<init>(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:95)
```

I am convinced this is a problem of Python package versions, as another user had a similar problem with a previous version of Spark ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63800810/)). However I did not succeed to find the right version of pandas/pyarrow to use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to open a ticket with AWS Support and they fixed the issue. Part of the solution was to use this in the first notebook cell:

```
%%configure -f
{
    "conf": {
        "spark.pyspark.python":"python3",
        "spark.pyspark.virtualenv.enabled": "true",
        "spark.pyspark.virtualenv.type": "native", 
        "spark.pyspark.virtualenv.bin.path": "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv"
        
    }
}
```

Comment: The other part is to update virtualenv on all the cluster nodes by making this a bootstrap action:  `sudo pip3 install virtualenv`. Note that it still affects the current EMR-6.14.0 with spark 3.4.1.